# How to make a checkbox without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to make a simple app with 3 fields like this:

```
    <div id = "nameInput" >Name:</div><input id = "nameInputField" type = "text" name = "userName" />
    <div id = "emailInput" >Email:</div><input id = "emailInputField" type = "text" name = "email" />
    <input id = "termsCheck" type = "checkbox" name = "terms" />
```

The problem I am having is that I keep needing to try to wrap it in a form to get the checkbox to register as checked when it is. I DO NOT want to use a form because I don't ever want to submit anything.

Here is the JS for the checkbox as well. It is always marked as unchecked:

```
if ($('#terms').checked == true) {
    //Rest of code
```

Is there a way to make this without using a form or is there a reason that my checkbox is never registered as checked?

Comment: I am assuming you are using jQuery based on the code in your question

Comment: why would you NOT want to use a form? input is defined to always be part of a form

Comment: I keep getting issues with the form always submitting. I thought it would be easier without a form. I was also curious if it was possible

Comment: You could always wrap it in a form and not include a submit button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<input id = "termsCheck" type="checkbox" name="terms" />
```

JS:

pre jQuery 1.6:

```
if($('#termsCheck').is(':checked')){}
```

after jQuery 1.6:

```
if($('#termsCheck').prop('checked')){}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two issues.

First, you're referencing the name of the input instead of its ID.

Second, in order to use the `checked` property, it must be done on the DOM element, not the jQuery object.

```
if( $('#termsCheck')[0].checked ) {
    // ...
}
```

This is accessing the DOM element at index `0` of the jQuery object, then accessing its `checked` property.

You could also use the [`get()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to retrieve the DOM element.

```
if( $('#termsCheck').get(0).checked ) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you DON'T want to use jQuery, you could do something like:

```
<input id = "termsCheck" type = "checkbox" name = "terms" />
```

and refer to it this way:

```
if (document.getElementById("termsCheck").checked) {
}
```

Comment: If you change getElementByID to getElementById it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the checked state differently

```
$('#terms').is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

the jquery object (witch im asuming your using) dosent have an checked field
so that fill be false yes

what you can do is

```
 $("#terms").is(":checked")
```